# I can't write a file

Tags: c, file, dynamic, printf

I'm trying for first time writing a file in C, but I get and I can't figure out why. The variable `nombre` is the name of the file I create, then I want to write in this file the contents of the string `testo` but I always get an error:

`process return -1073741819`

```
char* inserisci (char*);

int main() {
    char *nombre=NULL,letra;
    char*testo=NULL;

    int i=0;
    printf("Type file name: ");
    nombre=malloc(sizeof(char));
    letra=getche();
    *(nombre+i)=letra;
    while(letra!='\r'){
        i++;
        nombre=realloc(nombre,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
        letra=getche();
        *(nombre+i)=letra;
    }
    *(nombre+i)='\0';
    printf("\n");
    testo=inserisci(testo);
    fopen(nombre,"w+");
    fprintf(nombre,"%s",testo);
    return 0;
}

char* inserisci (char* testo){
    char letra;
    int i=0;
    testo=malloc(sizeof(char));
    letra=getche();
    *(testo+i)=letra;
    while(letra!='\r'){
        i++;
        testo=realloc(testo,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
        letra=getche();
        *(testo+i)=letra;
    }
    *(testo+i)='\0';
    return testo;
}
```

Comment: and this error is...?

Comment: Your fprintf usage is incorrect, you need to put a pointer to the file as the first parameter,  not the file name itself.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but reallocating byte per byte with `realloc` is really a bad idea.

Comment: It's terribly inefficient, plus any of the calls might fail, which you're not testing for, and so might crash your program.

Comment: what's the best solution instead?

Comment: Hm *best* may be a matter of opinion, but one common and imho useful pattern: 1.) allocate a buffer big enough to hold what you think is sane for the data 2.) track buffer usage in a variable 3.) each time your buffer is full, double the size and use realloc. See [this example](https://github.com/Zirias/badxml/blob/master/src/example.c#L6) where I use this strategy for reading a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 fprintf(nombre,"%s",testo);
            ^here file pointer is needed not the char pointer containing files path or name.
```

Declare a file pointer

```
         FILE *fp;
         fp=fopen(nombre,"w+');
         fprintf(fp,"%s",testo);
```

This is format of `fprintf`

```
      int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```